# com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException on Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-multidex

I have a library I use for Espresso tests that when I added to my project I'm not able to compile my tests.

Gradle outputs this error

```
Caused by: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$8.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:565)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:276)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:574)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:198)
```

Which is really weird because I already have multiDex enabled in my project

My Project build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 21
            versionName versionNameFromGitTagVia()
            versionCode versionCodeFromJenkins()
            multiDexEnabled true

            testInstrumentationRunner "app.test.general.InstrumentationRunner" ...
}
dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestImplementation project(':test-utils')
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}
```

My Application Class

```
public class RiderApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
  ....
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<application
    android:name=".RiderApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:theme,android:icon">
```

Removing the library solves the problem

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
I tried to fix it in several ways, and I discovered that this only happends when I include the library as

```
androidTestImplementation
```

But when used as a regular

```
implementation
```

The dex error disappears

Really strange

EDIT

It only happens with gradle 3.0.1, if I go back to gradle 2.3.3 the problem is no more

Comment: Create `Application` Class. check logic https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430306/3395198

Comment: Thanks @IntelliJAmiya but as I mentioned my app already supports multidex

Comment: have Application class ?

Comment: I do, and it already extends MultiDexApplication

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Already have

Comment: Please show your `Application` class.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have added it to the question, can you look now?

Comment: `multiDexEnabled true` remove `=` sign. then `Clean-Rebuild-Restart-RUN`.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya No help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159641/discussion-between-orelzion-and-intellij-amiya).

Comment: I was facing the same problem and resolved it by setting minSdkVersion to 21. @orelzion did you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by updating gradle build tools from version 3.0.1 to 3.1.0-rc02.
So please try:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-rc02'
```

Comment: This is what fixed it for me, upgrading to 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a strange one but it has happened before.

I've stumbled upon [this thread](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard/issues/40), whish suggested this addition:

```
dexOptions {
    jumboMode = true

    // Avoid the OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded:
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

This should handle the issue of the string number being too large, as opposed to the number of methods being too large.

More on jumbo mode vs multidex here: [Android: Jumbo Mode vs Multidex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495212/android-jumbo-mode-vs-multidex)

Happy testing.

Comment: Thank you! It looked promising, but unfortunately this didn't help either . I added some findings to the original question

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many hours of testing I finally got it to run.

I have changed several things in the project, so I can't tell what was the one that caused the problem, but for the greater good I'll write here everything I did and I hope that if someone will ever encounter with such problem at least one solution will help her.

So I changed minSdkVersion to 21. Yes, it wasn't a requirement with Android Studio 2.3.3 but apparently it is now if you're going to use espresso.
But worry not, your application can still support older versions when not testing. To configure it that way I've added this to my `build.gradle`

```
def isTest = gradle.startParameter.taskNames.find { it.contains("AndroidTest") }
        if (isTest != null) {
            println("is test true")
            minSdkVersion 21
        } else {
            println("is not test")
            minSdkVersion 16
        }
```

Other than that, I updated multiDex dependency from `1.0.1` to `1.0.2` and I enforced that on all dependencies.

I also updated `guava` library to `com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android`, which led to a dependency conflict that I solved by forcing another library (all forcing strategy is posted below).

I then had a dependency conflict with `espresso-web` that I needed to enforce too.

This is my resolution strategy at the moment

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
            force 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0-android'
            force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
            force 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.0.1'
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps anyone, thank you so much for all the people who tried to help, you brought many ideas that helped me succeeded with the final resolution